# c# If statement block executing even when false

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement

So I am getting event data from Google Calendar event. I have a variable `item` that is of class `Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event`. There is a property called `Start`, which is when the even starts. If it's set at a certain time of day, then `Start.DateTime` will have a value. If it's an all-day event, then `Start.DateTime` will be null, and it will have a separate property `Start.Date` which is  a string for some reason. If `Start.DateTime` doesn't have a value, I want to get the `Start.Date` value insead. Here's the relevant code:

```
if (item.Start.DateTime.HasValue)
                {
                    newEvent.Start = (DateTime)item.Start.DateTime;
                    newEvent.End = (DateTime)item.End.DateTime;
                } else
                {
                    string StartDay = item.Start.Date;
                    string EndDay = item.End.Date;
                }
```

So when I run it on a date with a regular DateTime, I see this:

[image: DateTime.HasValue is true]

And it assigns a value to NewEvent.Start as it should. Great.

Now I run it with an all-day event where Start.DateTime is null:

[image: DateTime.HasValue is false]

So it should skip to the else statement, but it doesn't:

[image: Start still gets a value]

The newEvent.Start is still assigned a value, even though the condition is false. And the else statement isn't executed. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `DateTime` is a value-type it can´t have a non-value. What you see in the debugger is thus only the default-value for it, however your if-statement is not executed. It is only the debugger showing *anything* for your variable because it can´t show `null`. Obviously your member `Start` is a `DateTime` whilst `item.Start` returns a `DateTime?`.

When you put a breakpoint into the statements within `if` you´ll notice it´ll never get executed thus. Only the debugger is creating this value, nothing is assigned to your variable - except its default value which apparently is the 1st of Jan. 0001 when *defining* your variable. So whereever you define `newEvent`, this is the line where this default-value is set - not within the `if`-statement.

Comment: Yes I see now. It was working correctly, the DateTime just had the default value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It **is** skipping the code as you expect. But `newEvent.Start` has a value anyway, probably because it is of type DateTime, which cannot be null.

Answer (score 1):

That is the default value of DataTime type. You can use Nullable DataTime for your purpose.

```
DateTime? d = null;
bool boolNotSet = d.HasValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a structure in C#; one consequence of this is its member variables are always initialized, in this case the value 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM, which is also equal to `DateTime.MinValue` or `default(DateTime)`.  Another consequence is that structures are passed by value and cannot be null.

If you wish to have a DateTime "null" state, you might want to use `Nullable<T>` (or the shorthand ?) in your event class:

```
public class NewEvent {
    public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

`Nullable<T>` gives you the `HasValue` property to check if the object has been assigned a value or not.

Comment: I should have specified this is actually of class DateTime? meaning it is nullable. That's why the .HasValue property exists (there would be no .HasValue property if it wasn't nullable.) That's also why the .HasValue statement is shown as false in the conditional.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Sorry I misunderstood.